# If someone said אהבה רבה before ברכת התורה without having in mind for ברכות התורה us he יוצא Birchos Hatorah?

Tags: tefilla, birchos-hatorah

According to the Ramban (השגות לספר המצוות להרמב"ם [שכחת העשין טו](https://www.sefaria.org/Hasagot_HaRamban_on_Sefer_HaMitzvot,_Positive_Commandments_Omitted_by_Rambam.15.1?with=all&lang=he)) that birchos Hatorah is a Mitzvah מדאורייתא, If someone said אהבה רבה before ברכת התורה without having in mind for ברכות התורה is he יוצא?

Does this depend on the מחלוקת whether מצוות צריכות כוונה? Or maybe אהבה רבה is assumed not to be ברכות התורה unless specifically intended as such. Thus even if מצוות אין צריכות כוונה he still would not be yotze?

Comment: Why does this require that Birchas HaTorah be de’oraisa? Even if it were d’Rabbanan, we still have this same machlokes of mitzvos tzerichos kavana (just take a look at sefiras ha’omer, which most consider to be d’Rabbanan nowadays).

Comment: @DonielF Many are strict for the opinion that Mitzvot Tzrikhot Kavana only for Mitzvot Deoraita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch ([OC 47:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.47.7?with=all&lang=bi)) says that the Bracha of Ahavat olam (ahava raba) is poter birkat hatora, as long as he learns right away without a hefsek.

> ברכת אהבת עולם פוטרת ברכת התורה אם למד מיד בלי הפסק

The Mishna Berura, ([47:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.47.14?with=all&lang=bi)) (who also [holds](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.47.1?with=all&lang=bi) that the bracha is Medeoraita,) explains that it seems that even if one did not have in mind to be *yotze* with birkat hatorah, it's still enough, and he doesn't have to say it again later.

> פוטרת - שיש בה מעין ברכת התורה ותן בלבנו ללמוד וללמד לשמור ולעשות ולקיים וכו' ולכאורה מדסתם משמע דאפילו לא כיון בעת הברכה לפטור בזה בה"ת סגי ועיין בבה"ל:

Comment: But are these sources speaking according to the position of the Ramban?

Comment: Maybe you should quote the first Mishnah Berurah in the Siman, which concludes that Birchas HaTorah is d’Oraisa, like the Rambam.

Comment: @DonielF thanks for pointing that out. Edited

Comment: @DonielF IIRC the MB contradicts himself a few times about that, so it's not so clear what he actually holds

Comment: @DoubleAA Really he just quotes earlier Rishonim and Achronim on the topic throughout the Siman. I say he concludes, but I’m really just assuming that based on the fact that he seems to quote more evidence that supports that opinion.